# SQL Group by Child Table with conditions

Tags: sql, group-by, having

I have simplified it a bit to ask this question. So just run with the tables as they are please.

I have two tables

Parent Table columns are

```
ParentId,Parent_FirstName,Parent_LastName
```

Child Table columns are

```
ChildId,Child_FirstName,Child_LastName,ParentId,Parent_FirstName,Parent_LastName
```

Parent Table has one record

```
1,Joe,Bloggs
```

Child Table has three records

```
1,Bob,Lawrence,1,,

2,Sam,Hunt,NULL,Joe,Bloggs

3,Sam,Hunt,1,,
```

I want to be able to get the following by using a query

```
Joe Bloggs Bob Lawrence
Joe Bloggs Sam Hunt
```

but.. i want to be able to link the parent and child table by the following

```
1)If there is a parentid on the child table then link using the parentid
2)Else compare the parent_first and parent_lastname in the child table with that of the child tables
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
SELECT
  p.Parent_FirstName,
  p.Parent_LastName,
  c.Child_FirstName,
  c.Child_LastName
FROM parent AS p
INNER JOIN child AS c ON p.ParentId = c.ParentId;
```

See it in action here:

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b400b2/1).

This will give you:

```
| PARENT_FIRSTNAME | PARENT_LASTNAME | CHILD_FIRSTNAME | CHILD_LASTNAME |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|              Joe |          Bloggs |             Bob |       Lawrence |
|              Joe |          Bloggs |             Sam |           Hunt |
```

---

**Note that:** This query will `JOIN` the two tables using a simple `JOIN` using the first condition to link the two tables:

> 1)If there is a parentid on the child table then link using the
>   parentid

and it will be enough; it will give you what you are looking for, ***but*** for the second condition that you want to link the child table with the parent table with it:

> 2)Else compare the parent_first and parent_lastname in the child table
>   with that of the child tables

You can add the following condition with `OR`:

```
 c.ParentId IS NULL 
 AND c.Parent_FirstName = p.Parent_FirstName
 AND c.Parent_LastName  = p.Parent_LastName
```

Something like this:

```
SELECT 
  p.Parent_FirstName,
  p.Parent_LastName,
  c.Child_FirstName,
  c.Child_LastName
FROM parent AS p
INNER JOIN child AS c ON p.ParentId = c.ParentId 
                      OR (c.ParentId IS NULL 
                          AND c.Parent_FirstName = p.Parent_FirstName
                          AND c.Parent_LastName  = p.Parent_LastName)
```

This will give you the same result, but with duplicate rows:

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b400b2/6)

Like this:

```
| PARENT_FIRSTNAME | PARENT_LASTNAME | CHILD_FIRSTNAME | CHILD_LASTNAME |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|              Joe |          Bloggs |             Bob |       Lawrence |
|              Joe |          Bloggs |             Sam |           Hunt |
|              Joe |          Bloggs |             Sam |           Hunt |
```

Add the `DISTINCT` to the `SELECT` to eliminate the duplicate rows.

---

**Disclaimer:**

This assuming that you are not looking for a recursive query.